# Load existing data catalog programmatically

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, kedro

1. I want to write pytest unit test in **Kedro 0.17.5**. They need to perform integrity checks on dataframes created by the pipeline.
   These dataframes are specified in the `catalog.yml` and already persisted successfully using `kedro run`. The `catalog.yml` is in `conf/base`.
2. I have a test module `test_my_dataframe.py` in `src/tests/pipelines/my_pipeline/`.

How can I load the data catalog based on my `catalog.yml` programmatically from within `test_my_dataframe.py` in order to properly access my specified dataframes?

Or, for that matter, how can I programmatically load the whole project context (including the data catalog) in order to also execute nodes etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For unit testing, we test just the function which we are testing, and everything external to the function we should mock/patch. Check if you really need kedro project context while writing the unit test.
2. If you really need project context in test, you can do something like following

```py
from kedro.framework.project import configure_project
from kedro.framework.session import KedroSession

with KedroSession.create(package_name="demo", project_path=Path.cwd()) as session:
    context = session.load_context()
    catalog = context.catalog
```

or you can also create pytest fixture to use it again and again with scope of your choice.

```py
@pytest.fixture
def get_project_context():
    session = KedroSession.create(
        package_name="demo",
        project_path=Path.cwd()
    )
    _activate_session(session, force=True)
    context = session.load_context()
    return context
```

Different args supported by KedroSession create you can check it here https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/0.17.5/kedro.framework.session.session.KedroSession.html#kedro.framework.session.session.KedroSession.create

To read more about pytest fixture you can refer to https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session

Comment: Thanks! Regarding your point 1: I was looking into https://greatexpectations.io for data tests. But for my purposes I figured that pytest might be more lightweight. Is https://pypi.org/project/kedro-great/ the recommended way to integrate kedro with greatexpectations currently? The package was last updated in 2020.

Comment: There currently isn't a well maintained plug-in available. You can build your own integration with Hooks, but I also am increasingly impressed by pandera which is super easy to integrate with Kedro.